# Git still tracks files in gitignore file

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

i am having the following problem with gitignore in windows (that i used in combination with vscode, if this info is important)

i tried a simple example in order not to complicate things.

my root folder contains:

```
maininterface.py
.gitignore
logs/dev.log
```

my gitignore file has only one line:

```
logs/
```

when typing git status i get the following:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        logs/
        maininterface.py
```

Am I missing something? the directory logs should not be in the untracked files.
I tried looking for solutions, many people suggest `git rm --cached logs`
This does not work for me, I get :

```
fatal: pathspec 'logs' did not match any files
```

(I also tried `git rm --cached logs/dev.log` , same problem)

BTW I haven't used git add on any of the files.

Thank you if you have a tip...

Comment: can you run `git check-ignore -v logs` and add the output to your question ?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. the command gives no problem. but git status gives still the same output

Comment: Does it give an output ? or is it silent ?

Comment: it is silent... no output

Comment: this means your folder isn't matched by any `gitignore` pattern.

Comment: ok. and is there any solution to that?

Comment: I tried the steps and as soon as I add `.gitignore` the `logs` dir disappears from the status. the `check-ignore` gives the following output for me `.gitignore:1:logs/      logs`. use a tool like `od` to see what bytes are in `.gitignore` or use the hexeditor extension of VSC

Comment: could you be more specific with the Hexeditor, please. What should i do with it?

Comment: problem solved, with notepad++ thanks!

Comment: you should install cygwin with the basic command line tools like od for this kind of cases. UCS-2 LE suggests you have a 16-bit Unicode format with Little Endian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your `.gitignore` file is free of parasite characters.

For example : a BOM at the beginning of the file would make git try to look for `"{\xEF\xBB\xBF}logs"`.

---

[edit] : I had forgotten powershell writes in `UTF-16` (or `UCS-2`) by default, you correctly found that, on top of a BOM, your file was actually encoded in `UCS-2`.

Comment: .gitignore is free of parasites... it only contains one line. and i created it specifically with the echo command...

Comment: are you on Windows ? powershell for example adds a BOM to the stdout of a command ...

Comment: either check the hex content of your file (@rioV8 suggests `od`), or open it in an editor which would tell you if there is one (e.g : Notepad++)

Comment: yes I am on windows. Can you please tell me how to check if this BOM is added or not?

Comment: Do you have Notepad++ installed ? If you open a file with Notepad++, you will see an annotation at the bottom saying `UTF-8 with BOM` or `UTF-8 no BOM`. Somewhere in the menus (`Edit` if I recall correctly) there is an item to explicitly convert to `UTF-8 no BOM`.

Comment: another hack is to start your .gitignore file with an empty line, or a comment line ... :)

Comment: I have the usual Notepad that comes with windows...

Comment: try the "first empty line" trick, and see if `check-ignore -v` works. If it does, you can hunt for BOMs, or simply start with a `# some comment` line

Comment: So, I tried the empty line at the beginning of the file. still not working. check ignore is silent, and git status is still unchanged

Comment: if it is relevant for you, i tried check ignore -v logs/  and i get as a reponse: .gitignore:4:   logs/     but git status is still unchanged

Comment: I opened my file with Notepad++ , it is said on the bottom UCS-2 LE BOM . is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
with Notepad ++, it was the encoding issue...!

Thank you very much for the help